# Send HTML Email that contains stylesheet

Tags: html, css, email, server-side

I send an email but Gmail don't read my html head.

I need to use from @font-face.

I send this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="http://myAddress.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="style1">Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to see this:

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0aT6.png)

but i see this:

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO8D8.png)

Comment: Usually email clients will strip out any links to style sheets, so this approach will probably never work consistently (or at all). Your best approach is to use inline styles.

Comment: Did you try using inline or embedded CSS instead of an external stylesheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail's CSS support is very... limited to say: [The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). So you are probably out of luck here and need to rewrite the code.

Also see [Understanding Gmail and CSS: Part 1](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1) for more details on how to solve this. You need to inline all your CSS, but there are tools available.

Comment: MailChimp has a similar CSS guide http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/ (worth mentioning in your answer)

Comment: According to the link I posted, GMail doesn't support this.